# Submit a form using anchor tag to open pdf in new window

Tags: php, javascript, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM-site that generates a pdf-file when submitting a form. All that is working fine, but I have a problem with the pdf not opening in a new window(open safari..) when started from home screen on iPhone.
It seems that I'm not the only one having problem with this, but I havn't found a working solution yet. I have no problem opening a new window in safari if I link to a static pdf with an anchor tag. My conclusion is that if I submit my form with an anchortag everything will work..! 
However when i try with the following code the result is just the same as if I post my form with a regular submit button.

Can anyone please help me with another solution? Or maybe tweak this so that it works?

This is my form:

```
 <form name="pdf" action="pdf_report1.php" data-ajax="false" target="_blank" id="pdf_report" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $customer_id; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="date_from" value="<?php echo $date_from; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="date_to" value="<?php echo $date_to; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="maskin_id" value="<?php echo $maskin_id; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="akeri_id" value="<?php echo $akeri_id; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="littra_id" value="<?php echo $littra_id; ?>" >
<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('pdf_report').submit();" data-role="button">Create PDF</a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this problem and not being able to solve it as I wished using the form, I went a different way. 
Instead of using the form I simply just added all the values I needed in the URL and extracted it using get on the target page. Maybe not the most elegant way to do it but it works for me.
Now the PDF opens in a new window in safari when the web app is started from the home screen on iPhone just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put these line into pdf_report1.php

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

Comment: OK, I tried that but it doesn't seem to have any effect. pdf_report1.php is in fact a FPDF page that outputs a pdf, and that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about doing it with iPhone, but adding the `target = '_blank'` should force it to open in a blank tab or page, depending on the default for that broswer. EX:

```
<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('pdf_report').submit();" data-role="button" target="_blank">Create PDF</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Brandon for your answer. However I have already tried this. I have also tried data-ajax="false" which according to JQM both would work. And it does but only if I have just a plain anchor tag to an pdf or another type of page...